# How to validate in view pager after swiped?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Let's say I've some fragments in my view pager. I want to make some validation in `onPageSelected()` method before next fragment. I don't want to go next fragment unless validation is succeeded. Another question is, how can I know the previous position? If I swipe left to right, previous position will be position-1 and if right to left, it will be position+1. But is there anyway to know the direction that user swiped. In the following picture, it should stay remain (without going to next fragment) if the user fill nothing. Hoping the correct answer..

[image]

Comment: "I don't want to go next fragment if it's not valid" -- then do not use a `ViewPager`. If you want a wizard, write a wizard.

Comment: Ok.., there's always a way. I'm gonna show you how to make it with pager within few days. Now, I'm doing research.

Comment: My point is that what you are doing is user-hostile. Whether it is technically possible does not help if users get pissed when they swipe to another page, only to find themselves being forced back to some previous page. If you don't want people swiping between pages, don't use a `ViewPager`.

Comment: My customer asked me to do so, 10 screen for 9 input fragments like above image and 1 submit fragment. If I put the validation to the submit button, I shouldn't make user swiping back til he reached the field_required_fragment. So, making validation before another question appear is simple and beautiful. I've seen other apps do so as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After few hours research, I got my solution. That's it.

```
private OnPageChangeListener pageChangeListener = new OnPageChangeListener() {

    int currentPosition = 0;

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int newPosition) {

        // my code
        boolean isValid = false; // <-- here, you need to check yourself valid or not
        if (!isValid) {
            pager.setCurrentItem(currentPosition);
        }else{
            pager.setCurrentItem(newPosition);
            currentPosition = newPosition;
        }
    } }
```

User can't see the next screen if not valid no matter how many time he swipe the pager.

Answer (score 0):

private OnPageChangeListener pageChangeListener = new OnPageChangeListener() {

```
int currentPosition = 0;

@Override
public void onPageSelected(int newPosition) {

    // my code
    boolean isValid = false; // <-- here, you need to check yourself valid or not
    if (!isValid) {
        pager.setCurrentItem(currentPosition);
    }else{
        pager.setCurrentItem(newPosition);
        currentPosition = newPosition;
    }
} }
```

working for first time only

Comment: try boolean isValid = false || newPosition == 0;