# how to fix" 3 fragment in One activity with viewPager need validation first two page then possible to go third page"

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

I want to create a createOrderActivity where has three fragments like Service info, ScheduleInfo, confirmation

the service info fragment has editText 
if click NextButton(which is situated CreateOrderActivity) check validation editText first. then move ScheduleFragment page. 
if first two pages validation ok then move to Confirmation Fragment page.

Here is the FragmentViewpagerAdapter class

```
public class FragmentViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private final List<Fragment> fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
private final List<String> fragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

public FragmentViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
    super(manager);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return fragmentList.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return fragmentList.size();
}

public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
    fragmentList.add(fragment);
    fragmentTitleList.add(title);
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return fragmentTitleList.get(position);
}
```

}

In CreateOrderActivity class

```
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            boolean checkSch= false;
            if (position == 1) {

                ServiceInfoFragment serviceInfoFragment = new ServiceInfoFragment();

                //checking validation from ServiceInfoFragment fragment Class
                if (serviceInfoFragment.checkServiceValidation()) {


                    checkSch = true;
                    //Toast.makeText(CreateOrderActivity.this, "Validation okay", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else {
                    checkSch = false;
                   // Toast.makeText(CreateOrderActivity.this, "Please check validation", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    pagerCreateOrder.setCurrentItem(position-1);
                }
            }
            if (position == 2) {

                if (checkSch){
                    ScheduleFragment scheduleFragment = new ScheduleFragment();
                    if (scheduleFragment.checkScheduleValidation()) {
                        Toast.makeText(CreateOrderActivity.this, "Validation okay", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(CreateOrderActivity.this, "Please check S validation", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        pagerCreateOrder.setCurrentItem(position-1);
                    }

                }else {

                    Toast.makeText(CreateOrderActivity.this, "Please check validation", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    pagerCreateOrder.setCurrentItem(position-2);
                }


            }


        }
```

> //checking checkScheduleValidation() in ScheduleFragment class. return null exception

*bellow mehtod declear in Fragment *

```
    public boolean checkServiceValidation(){


    return true;
}
```

I upload this Image

[image: I did like this image]

[I used this Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25833404/how-to-validate-in-view-pager-after-swiped)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution in my way. I have loaded three fragments in a viewpager. In the second fragment, there is one edittext. on clicking the next button, there is a validation for checking email. On the basis of validation next fragment is loaded. All the Fragments are loaded as singleton . You might have caused null pointer exception , because of multiple instance of fragments.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
private FragmentTwo fragmentTwo;

private ViewPager mViewPager;
Button back, next;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    back = findViewById(R.id.back);
    next = findViewById(R.id.next);
    next.setOnClickListener(this);
    back.setOnClickListener(this);

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.vp_viewpager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i1) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int i) {
            if (i==2){
                if (!fragmentTwo.checkEditText()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"False",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i-1);
                    return;
                }
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {

        }
    });


}

private void changeViewPagerPosition(int position) {
    int totalCount = mViewPager.getAdapter().getCount();
    if (position < 0 || position >= totalCount) {
        return;
    }
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    int currentViewpagerPosition = mViewPager.getCurrentItem();

    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.back:
            changeViewPagerPosition(currentViewpagerPosition - 1);
            break;
        case R.id.next:
            if (currentViewpagerPosition==1){
                if (!fragmentTwo.checkEditText()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Falsee",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }

            }
            changeViewPagerPosition(currentViewpagerPosition + 1);
            break;
    }
}

public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {

            case 0:
                return FragmentOne.newInstance(position);
            case 1:
                return fragmentTwo=FragmentTwo.getInstance();
            case 2:
                return FragmentThree.newInstance(position);
            default:
                return FragmentThree.newInstance(position);

        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

}

The Fragment 2

```
public  class FragmentTwo extends Fragment  {

EditText email;
private static FragmentTwo fragment=null;


public FragmentTwo() {
}

public static FragmentTwo getInstance() {
    if (fragment == null){
        fragment = new FragmentTwo();
    }
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);
   return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


    email = getView().findViewById(R.id.editText);

}


public boolean emailValidator()
{
    Pattern pattern;
    Matcher matcher;
    final String EMAIL_PATTERN = "^[_A-Za-z0-" +
            "9-]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";
    pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
    matcher = pattern.matcher(email.getText().toString());
    return matcher.matches();
}


public Boolean checkEditText(){
    if (emailValidator()){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: I am getting an error   This method declare in first fragment(ServiceInfo)  public boolean validator(){

        String etProduct = etProductName.getText().toString();
        if (etProduct.isEmpty()||etProduct==null){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public boolean checkServiceValidation(){
        
        if (validator()){

            return true;
        }
        
        return false;
    }

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
        at usl.mehedi.consumerservice.ui.fragment.serviceinfo.ServiceInfoFragment.validator(ServiceInfoFragment.java:135)
        at usl.mehedi.consumerservice.ui.fragment.serviceinfo.ServiceInfoFragment.checkServiceValidation(ServiceInfoFragment.java:145)
        at usl.mehedi.consumerservice.ui.activity.createorder.CreateOrderActivity$1.onPageSelected(CreateOrderActivity.java:104)

Comment: You have to load the fragments in viewpager adapter like what i have done in the answer.

Comment: @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                boolean checkSch= false;
                if (position == 1) {

                    ServiceInfoFragment serviceInfoFragment = new ServiceInfoFragment();

         
                    if (serviceInfoFragment.checkServiceValidation()) {

                        checkSch = true;
                      
                    }else {
                        checkSch = false;
                  
                        pagerCreateOrder.setCurrentItem(position-1);
                    }
                }

Comment: sorry I loaded it the Activiy    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        pagerAdapter = new FragmentViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        pagerAdapter.addFragment(new ServiceInfoFragment(), "Service info");
        pagerAdapter.addFragment(new ScheduleFragment(), "Schedule");
        pagerAdapter.addFragment(new ConfirmOrderFragment(), "Confirmation");

        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    }
okay. doing.

Comment: @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {

                case 0:
                    return FragmentOne.newInstance(position);
                case 1:
                    return fragmentTwo=FragmentTwo.getInstance();
                case 2:
                    return FragmentThree.newInstance(position);
                default:
                    return FragmentThree.newInstance(position);

            }

        }

Comment: got it. Thank you for being the reason I smile.

Comment: with pleasure !!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191055/discussion-between-amirul-and-gstephin).

Comment: I am getting an error as like before.   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Boolean com.amirul.viewpagedemo.FragmentTwo.checkEditText()' on a null object reference
        at com.amirul.viewpagedemo.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:81)

Comment: fragment two will be null in your case. Initialize fragmenttwo object like                 return fragmentTwo=FragmentTwo.getInstance();

Comment: I did.  private static FragmentTwo fragment=null;


    public FragmentTwo() {
    }

    public static FragmentTwo getInstance() {
        if (fragment == null){
            fragment = new FragmentTwo();
        }
        return fragment;
    }

Comment: initialization in Mainactivity?

Comment: I forget to declare FragmentTwo in MainActivity onCreate method. now working well.  again thanks. bro

Answer (score 0):

**kotlin: used this code = In one activity to attached frame View container then include all fragment** *is working fine*

**XML Activity**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dim_60_dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_survey_back"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_back"
            app:tint="@color/white"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dim_5_dp"
            android:padding="@dimen/dim_8_dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_house_id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/img_survey_back"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:fontFamily="@font/font_medium"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:text="@string/title_survey_info"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_house_id_num"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txt_house_id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/img_survey_back"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:fontFamily="@font/font_medium"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/dim_14_sp"
            android:text="House Id"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_no_connection"
        android:layout_below="@id/rl_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dim_30_dp"
        android:background="@color/black_alpha_5"
        android:textColor="@color/yellow"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_marginVertical="@dimen/dim_10_dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/font_bold"
        android:text="@string/no_internet_error"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/dim_10_dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/txt_no_connection">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/viewPagerIndicator"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginVertical="@dimen/dim_10_dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <com.tbuonomo.viewpagerdotsindicator.DotsIndicator
                android:id="@+id/dots_indicator"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:dotsColor="@color/colorSurveyEditGreenLight"
                app:dotsCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:dotsSize="16dp"
                app:dotsSpacing="4dp"
                app:dotsWidthFactor="2.5"
                app:selectedDotColor="@color/white"
                app:progressMode="true"
                />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_frame_layout"
            android:layout_below="@id/viewPagerIndicator"
            android:layout_above="@id/rl_btn_box"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
                android:id="@+id/view_pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layoutDirection="ltr"/>

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
                android:indeterminate="true"
                android:indeterminateTintMode="src_atop"
                android:indeterminateTint="@color/colorSurveyWhite"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:visibility="gone"/>

        </FrameLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_btn_box"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/dim_10_dp">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_next"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginVertical="@dimen/dim_20_dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dim_10_dp"
                android:background="@drawable/round_button"
                android:elevation="@dimen/dim_10_dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/font_bold"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:padding="@dimen/dim_10_dp"
                android:shadowColor="@color/colorGray"
                android:text="@string/btn_next"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:textColor="@color/colorSurveyTextBlue" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_done"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginVertical="@dimen/dim_20_dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dim_10_dp"
                android:background="@drawable/round_button"
                android:elevation="@dimen/dim_10_dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/font_bold"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:padding="@dimen/dim_10_dp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:shadowColor="@color/colorGray"
                android:text="@string/btn_done"
                android:textColor="@color/colorSurveyTextBlue"/>
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_update"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginVertical="@dimen/dim_20_dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dim_10_dp"
                android:background="@drawable/round_button"
                android:elevation="@dimen/dim_10_dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/font_bold"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:padding="@dimen/dim_10_dp"
                android:shadowColor="@color/colorGray"
                android:text="Update"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:textColor="@color/colorSurveyTextBlue"/>
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_back"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/round_button"
                android:text="@string/btn_back"
                android:fontFamily="@font/font_bold"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:layout_marginVertical="@dimen/dim_20_dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dim_10_dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorSurveyTextBlue"
                android:padding="@dimen/dim_10_dp"
                android:elevation="@dimen/dim_10_dp"
                android:shadowColor="@color/colorGray"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:visibility="gone"/>


        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**kotlin file - method only**

```
private fun setUpViewPager(){

    val fragmentList : MutableList< Fragment> = mutableListOf()
    fragmentList.add(SurveyPageOneFragment.newInstance(true))
    fragmentList.add(SurveyPageTwoFragment.newInstance(true))
    fragmentList.add(SurveyPageThreeFragment.newInstance(true))
    fragmentList.add(SurveyPageFourFragment.newInstance(true))
    fragmentList.add(SurveyPageFiveFragment.newInstance(true))

    surveyPagerAdapter = SurveyPagerAdapter(fragmentList,supportFragmentManager,lifecycle)
    binding.viewPager.adapter = surveyPagerAdapter
    binding.dotsIndicator.attachTo(binding.viewPager)

}
```

**setOnClick method**

```
private fun setOnClick(){
    binding.btnNext.setOnClickListener {
        if (binding.viewPager.currentItem < binding.viewPager.adapter?.itemCount!!){
            when (fragPosition) {
                0 -> {
                    Log.i("TAG", "Page 1: Position $fragPosition")
                    binding.viewPager.currentItem = binding.viewPager.currentItem +1
                }
                1 -> {
                    Log.i("TAG", "Page 2: Position $fragPosition")
                    binding.viewPager.currentItem = binding.viewPager.currentItem +1
                }
                2 -> {
                    Log.i("TAG", "Page 3: Position $fragPosition")
                    binding.viewPager.currentItem = binding.viewPager.currentItem +1
                }
                3 -> {
                    Log.i("TAG", "Page 4: Position $fragPosition")
                    binding.viewPager.currentItem = binding.viewPager.currentItem +1
                }
                4 -> {
                    Log.i("TAG", "Page 5: Position $fragPosition")
                    binding.viewPager.isUserInputEnabled = true
                    binding.viewPager.currentItem = binding.viewPager.currentItem +1
                }
            }
        }
    }


    binding.btnBack.setOnClickListener {
        if (binding.viewPager.currentItem != 0){
            binding.viewPager.currentItem = binding.viewPager.currentItem -1
        }
    }

    binding.btnDone.setOnClickListener {
        startActivity(Intent(context,SurveyCompleteActivity::class.java))
    }

    val onPageChangeCallback = object : OnPageChangeCallback(){
        override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
            Log.i("TAG", "PageChange: $position")
            fragPosition = position

            if (position == 0){
                binding.btnBack.visibility = View.GONE
            }else{
                binding.btnBack.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }

            if (position < binding.viewPager.adapter?.itemCount!! -1){
                binding.btnNext.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                binding.btnDone.visibility = View.GONE
            }else{
                binding.btnNext.visibility = View.GONE
                binding.btnDone.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                binding.viewPager.isUserInputEnabled = false
            }

        }
    }
    binding.viewPager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(onPageChangeCallback)
}
```

**view pager adapter**

```
class SurveyPagerAdapter(
private val fragmentList: MutableList< Fragment>,
fragment: FragmentManager,
lifecycle: Lifecycle) : FragmentStateAdapter(fragment,lifecycle){
override fun getItemCount(): Int = fragmentList.size

override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
    return fragmentList[position]
}

fun getFragmentName(position: Int) = fragmentList[position]

fun addFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
    fragmentList.add(fragment)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}}
```

**used similar fragment**

```
class SurveyPageFiveFragment : Fragment() {
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    _binding = FragmentSurveyPageFiveBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    return binding.root
}
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    init()
}
override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    _binding = null
}
companion object {
    @JvmStatic
    fun newInstance(isMyBoolean: Boolean) = SurveyPageFiveFragment().apply {
        val fragment = SurveyPageFiveFragment()
        arguments = Bundle().apply {
            putBoolean("REPLACE WITH A STRING CONSTANT", isMyBoolean)
        }
        fragment.arguments
        return fragment
    }
}}
```